# Citing references in a pagenote with author index and backrefs in bibliography at once

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, memoir, pagenote, authorindex

I have a question about citing references in page notes.  I would like the backrefs in the bibliography to include the page number of the text where the page note citation number occurs.  I would also like to include an author index back to the same pages.

Here is my MWE.  In the first section 1.1 I use regular citations. In 1.2 I use the page notes.  The bibliography backrefs point to the pagenote citations on the notes page but not the number citations on pages 4 and 5. I'm not sure the easiest way to create a pagenote with a note with backref in to the text where the page note number is in the bibliography and enter into the author index all at once.  Thank you very much in advance!

```
\begin{filecontents*}{jobname.bib}
@book{writer2003,
title={Squidman Follies: A Chronical of Heartbreaking Disasters},
author={Scribbler, David P. and Marker, Alan R.},
publisher={Squidhouse},
year={2003}}

@article{scribe2011,
author={Scribe, Charles A.},
journal={Squidman Monthly},
title={His cruel tenticles},
year={2011},
volume = {23},
number = {4},
pages = {56--74}}

@article{genius2010,
author={Genius, Andy M. and Writer, Jason T.},
journal={Creation Science Quarterly},
title={Squidman's Apparent Deafness},
year={2010},
volume = {7},
number = {16},
pages = {1--14}
}
\end{filecontents*} 

% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = arara
% arara: xelatex
% arara: biber
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex


\documentclass[
ebook,
openright,
11pt, % Type size.
final]{memoir}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    %
\usepackage[italian,american]{babel} % English please
\usepackage[final]{microtype} % Less badboxes
\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}
\usepackage{multind}
\usepackage{type1ec}
\usepackage[style=italian]{csquotes} 
\usepackage[natbib, style=philosophy-modern,backend=biber, backref]{biblatex}
\usepackage[unicode=true, bookmarks=true, bookmarksnumbered=false,  bookmarksopen=false, breaklinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 1}, colorlinks=false] {hyperref}

\hypersetup{final, pageanchor, pdftitle={Memoir1}, pdfsubject={Disappearing    hyperref example}, pdfkeywords={hyperref},pdfauthor=Great Author}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}


\makeindex[name=authors,title=Authors Index,columns=2]

%%%PAGENOTE
\makepagenote
\notepageref

\begin{document}

\part{The Universe of Squidman}

\chapter{How The Whole Shebang Started} 
\section{}
In the beginning there was nothing \autocite{writer2003}. Then there was giant Squidman \autocite{scribe2011}.  According to \citet{genius2010}  it was an unfortunate start to what could have been a really nice world.  \Textcite{scribe2011} wholeheartedly agreed with  \citeauthor{genius2010}, adding that Squidman's unrelenting cruelty toward the entities he created to inhabit the Earth planet indicates Squidman was totally unfit for the job. 

\citeauthor{writer2003} argued in Squidman's defense that He may not be as bad as we think, it is just that He sometimes falls asleep at the switch or that His tentacle capacity may be limited in some way. Some tenticles appear to be more kind and gentle, while others are cruel and distructive. Perhaps in some unknown way, He may actually mean well even when He appears cruel.  \citet{scribe2011} called these weak rationalizations for inexcusable behavior.

Despite numerous complaints about Squidman and unanswered requests for alternatives, the inhabitants of Earth appear to be stuck with Squidman for better or worse.  Squidman makes certain there is no way out of this   bugger even in death.


\section{Theories of Squidman's Origin} The two most popular current theories  amongst cosmologists regarding the origin of Squidman are that He is either an  Eternal Supernatural Entity (ESE) without origin or that He was created through  some unusual Quantum Flux (QF) in some higher spacetime   continuum.\pagenote{\citep{genius2010}}  

 The ESE theory has many followers at this time, but it begs the age old question,  ``Why o why does He exist at all?''  Also, what does it mean to be an eternal   being ``outside'' time?  It is a puzzler that has stumped the greatest minds  Squidman ever put on this planet.  The most common endpoint of such questioning is  to reply something along the lines that ``there is no \emph{why}, there just    \emph{is},'' or that it is ``\emph{beyond human capacity for understanding}\ldots   Get used to it and \emph{stop asking silly questions.''}\pagenote{\citep[42]  {writer2003} this is a little note about what he said}

Many have found these replies to be unsatisfactory because they feel there
\emph{just must be a scientific sounding answer to Why.}  Therefore the QF theorists have won a growing number of followers in the must-be-an-explanation camp because QF at least gives the mystery a scientific sounding name.  It will have to do at least until Squidman Himself provides better scientific sounding words for it.\pagenote{\citep[63]{scribe2011} although
 \citep[8]{genius2010} stated that Squidman does not understand the meaning of    human thoughts or vocalizations so alternatives provided by Squidman may just be   unusual squeaks and garbling noises.}

\blinddocument
\printpagenotes
\printbibliography 
\printindex[authors]


\end{document}
```